# IOS 7.0 : How to change values of layer.cornerRadius of a Navigation Button

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a method to change the corner radius of the default button in the navigation bar ?

Or the best way is to create a custom button and set this button in the navigation bar.

```
NSDictionary *rightAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:12.0], UITextAttributeFont,
                                 nil];

[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:rightAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.layer.cornerRadius = 5; //Don'tWork
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are going to want to create a BarButtonItem and then set that to the rightBarButtonItem with a custom view. Something like

```
 UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aView];
    item.customView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Good luck.